# Randomizing the color of a label

Tags: random, uilabel, uicolor

So I have a label and I want to be able to press the button I have setup and change the RGB values of the label. Seems simple but I am stumped. Any ideas?

```
NSInteger r = arc4random()%255;
NSInteger g = arc4random()%255;
NSInteger b = arc4random()%255;

_label.textColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:(arc4random_uniform(r/255.0)) green:(arc4random_uniform(g/255.0)) blue:(arc4random_uniform(b/255.0)) alpha:1] ;
```

Comment: What's the `(arc4random_uniform(r/255.0))` part supposed to do? Isn't `r` already random?

Comment: Also, what specifically isn't working?

Comment: The label color doesn't change as expected. I know the button is hooked up correctly because I already tested it with [UIColor greenColor]

Comment: arc4random()%255; generates a random integer from 0 to 255

Comment: Have you tried it with just `[UIColor colorWithRed:r/255.0 green:g/255.0 blue:b/255.0 alpha:1] ;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:(arc4random_uniform(r/255.0)) green:(arc4random_uniform(g/255.0)) blue:(arc4random_uniform(b/255.0)) alpha:1] ;
```

with

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:r/255.0 green:g/255.0 blue:b/255.0 alpha:1] ;
```

As you're currently calling `arc4_random_uniform()` on a random value that's already between 1 and 0 - which is exactly what you need to create a color.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the needless double use of random. Try this:

```
NSInteger r = arc4random_uniform(255);
NSInteger g = arc4random_uniform(255);
NSInteger b = arc4random_uniform(255);

UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:r / 255.0 green:g / 255.0 blue:b / 255.0 alpha:1];
_label.textColor = color;
```

What you had was calling `arc4random_uniform` on a random value between 0.0 and 1.0.